# ftp image upload causes image to be cut off swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, web-hosting

I am testing some code I found on github to upload an image via ftp to my website in a IOS app.  The problem is that when I try to upload a semi large image, the uploaded image seems to be corrupted with only the top part showing and the rest cut off.  It seems to work fine with smaller images or large image with higher compression.  Does anyone know what is causing this?

```
    let ftpup = FTPUpload(baseUrl: "mysite.com", userName: "user@mysite.com", password: "password", directoryPath: "")

    let image = UIImage(named: "medium")
    let imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1)

    ftpup.send(data: imagedata!, with: "cloudpowa.jpg", success: {(success) -> Void in
        if !success {
            print("Failed upload!")
        }
        else {
            print("image uploaded!")
        }
    })
```

ftp code from : https://gist.github.com/Nirma/fb9991be776107d17fdcd6ed2aa02876

```
import Foundation
import CFNetwork

public class FTPUpload {
    fileprivate let ftpBaseUrl: String
    fileprivate let directoryPath: String
    fileprivate let username: String
    fileprivate let password: String

    public init(baseUrl: String, userName: String, password: String, directoryPath: String) {
        self.ftpBaseUrl = baseUrl
        self.username = userName
        self.password = password
        self.directoryPath = directoryPath
    }
}


// MARK: - Steam Setup
extension FTPUpload {
    private func setFtpUserName(for ftpWriteStream: CFWriteStream, userName: CFString) {
        let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName)
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpWriteStream, propertyKey, userName)
    }

    private func setFtpPassword(for ftpWriteStream: CFWriteStream, password: CFString) {
        let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword)
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpWriteStream, propertyKey, password)
    }

    fileprivate func ftpWriteStream(forFileName fileName: String) -> CFWriteStream? {
        let fullyQualifiedPath = "ftp://\(ftpBaseUrl)/\(directoryPath)/\(fileName)"

        guard let ftpUrl = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, fullyQualifiedPath as CFString, nil) else { return nil }
        let ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, ftpUrl)
        let ftpWriteStream = ftpStream.takeRetainedValue()
        setFtpUserName(for: ftpWriteStream, userName: username as CFString)
        setFtpPassword(for: ftpWriteStream, password: password as CFString)
        return ftpWriteStream
    }
}


// MARK: - FTP Write
extension FTPUpload {
    public func send(data: Data, with fileName: String, success: @escaping ((Bool)->Void)) {

        guard let ftpWriteStream = ftpWriteStream(forFileName: fileName) else {
            success(false)
            return
        }

        if CFWriteStreamOpen(ftpWriteStream) == false {
            print("Could not open stream")
            success(false)
            return
        }

        let fileSize = data.count
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: fileSize)
        data.copyBytes(to: buffer, count: fileSize)

        defer {
            CFWriteStreamClose(ftpWriteStream)
            buffer.deallocate(capacity: fileSize)
        }

        var offset: Int = 0
        var dataToSendSize: Int = fileSize

        repeat {
            let bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(ftpWriteStream, &buffer[offset], dataToSendSize)
            if bytesWritten > 0 {
                offset += bytesWritten.littleEndian
                dataToSendSize -= bytesWritten
                continue
            } else if bytesWritten < 0 {
                // ERROR
                print("FTPUpload - ERROR")
                break
            } else if bytesWritten == 0 {
                // SUCCESS
                print("FTPUpload - Completed!!")
                break
            }
        } while CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(ftpWriteStream)

        success(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above and it's always returning an error, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

changed the following inside the ftp upload class from

```
while CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(ftpWriteStream)
```

to

```
while (true)
```

I found that it only writes once with the former.